# PHP reading file

Tags: php, file

I am trying to read a formatted file

`name` (read this into variable)

`10 10` (read into separate variables)

the rest into array

```
line

line

line

line
```

to clarify this is for an upload script which i already finished when a user uploads a file formatted like that it reads it in the way described above

```
 $fname =  'test.txt';

 $lines = file("$fname", "r");

while($lines as $currenline){

I am trying to put the name, width, height into variables
    then the rest into the array

}
```

will this help

Answer (score 0):

`$lines` already contains almost what you need, just pull out the relevant pieces.

```
$fname =  'test.txt';
$lines = file("$fname", "r");
$name = $lines[0];
list($height, $width) = explode(' ', $lines[1]);
$lines = array_slice($lines, 2);
```

Note this doesn't have any error checking, so you might want to add some.

As suggested in the comments you can also do this using `array_shift`:

```
$fname =  'test.txt';
$lines = file("$fname", "r");
$name = array_shift($lines);
list($height, $width) = explode(' ', array_shift($lines));
// $lines now contains only the rest of the lines in the file.
```

Comment: If you use `array_shift($lines)` in place of `$lines[0]` and `$lines[1]`, you can get rid of the `array_slice()`.

Comment: You're also manipulating the array 3 times instead of one time by using array_shift.

Comment: @smack0007 - I'm accessing the array twice and manipulating it once, not manipulating it 3 times...

Comment: @Mark E No, I meant using array_shift would do so. I'm for your method. ;-)

Comment: @Mark E  do i put this code inside the while lopp or do i remove the while loop

Comment: @hgbso, no, this would be in place of the loop.

Comment: $name = $lines[0];
list($var1, $var2) = explode(' ', $lines[1]);
$lines = array_slice($lines, 2);
this will take the first 2 lines

Comment: the first line name must be read into $name the second 10 10 has to be read into height and width

Comment: @hgbso, I've renamed `var1` and `var2` and now modified the snippets to show how they're used in context.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're asking for but maybe this can get you started:

```
$fname =  'test.txt';

$lines = file("$fname", "r");

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);
    $name = $parts[0];
    $width = $parts[1];
    $height = $parts[2];

    // Do whatever you want with the line data here
}
```

It assumes all input lines are well formatted of course.

Comment: After reading the question again I think Mark E's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh = fopen( $fname, 'r' );

$name = fgets( $fh );
$dimensions = split( ' ', fgets($fh) );
$length = $dimensions[0];
$width = $dimensions[1];

$lines = array();

while ( $line = fgets( $fh ) $lines[] = $line;
```

I never tested this, but it should work if your files are constant. The while loop maybe off, and need some re-working if it doesn't work, keeping in mind that fgets returns false if an error occurs or is unable to read the file.